# jQuery check and change Radio (html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

My HTML

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <link href="../../fuctions/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
        type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../fuctions/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../fuctions/functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../fuctions/jq.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="topbar">
            <div id="title">
                <!--Title-->After Landing</div>
            <div id="leftnav"> <a href="../../index_aerosoft.html">Home</a>
 <a href="katana_checklist_all.html">Overview</a>
                <!--AllChecklist-->
            </div>
            <div id="rightnav"> <a href="katan_checklist_engineshut-downl.html" id="a_next">Next</a>
            </div>
            <!--NextPage-->
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <ul class="pageitem">
                <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()"> <span class="name">Wing Flaps -<font color="red"> UP
                            </font></span>

                    <input name="1" type="radio"
                    value="other" />
                </li>
                <!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()"> <span class="name">Carburetor Heat -<font color="red"> OFF
                            </font></span>

                    <input name="2" type="radio"
                    value="other" />
                </li>
                <!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()"> <span class="name">Exterior Lights -<font color="red"> as required
                            </font></span>

                    <input name="3" type="radio"
                    value="other" />
                </li>
                <!--CheckpunktEnd-->
                <li class="radiobutton" onClick="checkChanges()"> <span class="name">Electric Fuel Pump -<font color="red"> OFF
                            </font></span>

                    <input name="4" type="radio"
                    value="other" />
                </li>
                <!--CheckpunktEnd-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> <a class="noeffect" href="#" onClick="resetChecklist();">Reset Checklist</a>
            <!--ResetChecklist-->
            <br />
            <br /> <a class="noeffect" href="#" onClick="openxyzDE();">xyz</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript

```
function checkChanges() {
    $('.radiobutton font').attr('color', 'red');

    font = $('.radiobutton :checked').closest('.radiobutton').find('font')

    if (this.flag) {
        this.checked = false;
    } else {
        font.attr('color', 'green');
    }

    this.flag = !this.flag;
}

$(function () {
    checkChanges();
    $('.radiobutton :radio').on('click', checkChanges);
});
```

[**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/syTQD/3/)

If someone clicks on the Radiobutton it gets unchecked and colour changes back to red but the colour or all, it should only change the colour of the one who get unchecked.

Comment: The font tag is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and will be removed from HTML5

Comment: So whats the way to handle it in html5?^^

Comment: Use CSS to style the spans

Comment: I modified your code using span and label, but there exists a plugin which modifies me stuff. Are you using labels/inputs in website with other scope?

Comment: yes i do its the iwebkit framework...

Comment: Yes, the modifies come from jquery ui, but i guess this is not a problem because you will load it only when you detect a mobile. Do not think that is a better idea to use checkboxes instead of radios ? According to you current code, i would use checkboxes.

Comment: Well i would also use them but in that point checkboxes are no option :/

Comment: Sounds strange. I won't post my solution to "answers" because there i used checkboxes. Anyway, you can check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/syTQD/7/

Comment: Well as i sad checkbox is no solution on these its really easy

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked: http://jsfiddle.net/syTQD/12/

the radio buttons should have proper names like: name="test[]"

html:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="title"><!--Title-->
        After Landing
    </div>  
    <div id="leftnav">
        <a href="../../index_aerosoft.html">Home</a>
        <a href="katana_checklist_all.html">Overview</a><!--AllChecklist-->
    </div>
    <div id="rightnav">
        <a href="katan_checklist_engineshut-downl.html"id="a_next">Next</a></div><!--NextPage-->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ul class="pageitem">
            <li class="radiobutton" >
                <span class="name">Wing Flaps -<font color="red"> UP
                </font></span>
                <input name="test[]" type="radio" value="other" />
            </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
            <li class="radiobutton">
                <span class="name">Carburetor Heat -<font color="red"> OFF
                </font></span>
                <input name="test[]" type="radio" value="other" />
            </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
            <li class="radiobutton" >
                <span class="name">Exterior Lights -<font color="red"> as required
                </font></span>
                <input name="test[]" type="radio" value="other" />
            </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
            <li class="radiobutton" >
                <span class="name">Electric Fuel Pump -<font color="red"> OFF
                </font></span>
                <input name="test[]" type="radio" value="other" />
            </li><!--CheckpunktEnd-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <a class="noeffect" href="#" onClick="resetChecklist();">Reset Checklist</a><!--ResetChecklist-->
        <br /><br />
        <a class="noeffect" href="#" onClick="openxyzDE();">xyz</a>
    </div>
```

js:

```
function checkChanges(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('input'))
        $(this).find('input').click();

    $('input:radio').each(function() {
        var color = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 'green' : 'red';
        $(this).parentsUntil('li').parent().find('font').attr('color',color);
    });
}

$('.pageitem .radiobutton').on('click',checkChanges);
```

Comment: Well problem is that you group the radio buttons and they needed to work like a checkbox here

Comment: change the name attribute as in your html

Comment: Well it loses the "uncheck" option for onClick see here http://jsfiddle.net/j4Wy7/